# android how to override onActivityResult on ACTION_PICK

Tags: java, android, androidx

So this is probably a stupid question, and I have seen a dozen other threads that talk about using the action picker intent to get an image from a gallery. and then you have to override onActivityResult to get the image data. I have the action coming up, but I can't figure out where to put the override?!

In the main activity I have this function

```
 private int GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
 private void pickFromGallery(){
        //Create an Intent with action as ACTION_PICK
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        // Sets the type as image/*. This ensures only components of type image are selected
        intent.setType("image/*");
        //We pass an extra array with the accepted mime types. This will ensure only components with these MIME types as targeted.
        String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,mimeTypes);
        // Launching the Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

this works fine.

Where do I put this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        //TODO: action
    }
}
```

Do I have to make my own class and extend ACTION_PICK somehow? the android documentation says those are strings. How can I determine the activity class for that? Or is there a shorthand way to override this? Every other post assumes you know where to put the override and I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Where do I put this" -- in the same activity or fragment where you `startActivityForResult()` call is.

Comment: O.o thank you!? So all intents within an activity automatically use onActivityResult within the same class they are called in? There is no observable connection to know that the code would do that

Comment: "So all intents within an activity automatically use onActivityResult within the same class they are called in?" -- yes. "There is no observable connection to know that the code would do that" -- FWIW, the connection between `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#starting-activities-and-getting-results). It is also covered in many books and courses on Android app development.